# Conditional formatting based on a value determined in each row in Excel for indeterminate amount of rows

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements

So I've got a cell that I'd like to colour orange if the date in that cell (lets say that cell is C1) is later than a date in a cell (lets say B1) somewhere on that same row. I can conditional format C1 to do this. All good. But then I'd like to create an indeterminate amount of rows like this. The two dates which I want to compare are in the same column in every row, but are compared per row. So one date in C1 will compare to B1. Another in C2 will compare to B2. There doesn't seem to be a conditional formatting technique to achieve this. Help?

P.s: A few things I've tried is using If statements but I can't seem to work out how to do it. I've also tried conditionally formatting one row and then using "insert" to replicate the condition formatting of the row above it but this seems to start comparing the inserted row to the date in the row above...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to apply conditional formatting to **a range** you can select the range first (and then that range will automatically become the "applies to" range in conditional formatting)

....then set the formula that applies to the first row of that range only

....then select appropriate formatting

As long as the formula uses the correct relative references that's sufficient to make it work for the entire range

So in your specific case you can select the whole column, or a specific range like `C1:C100` and then apply the formula that you need for the **first row** of that range, i.e.

`=C1>B1`

Another way to achieve this is to apply the formula to the first row only (as you have done already) then click on "format painter" (the little brush on the Home ribbon)......then select the range to copy to (e.g. C2:C100)